# Gradle (Flutter) does not use the cache

Tags: flutter, gradle

I'm giving Flutter a try, I'm totally new.

I added gradle in:
`[project_directory]/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:`

```
distributionUrl=file:///run/media/me/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

The first time I ran the `flutter run` command all dependencies were downloaded. But now when I create a new project, it downloads them again from the internet and doesn't use the previous cache. In fact, if I change something in `pubspec.yaml`, like adding assets, when I run `flutter run` it tries to download the internet dependencies again.

Am I missing any settings here?

Flutter 3.1.0 | Dart 2.18.0 | Gradle 7.2 | Linux

Answer (score -1):

for .yaml run 'flutter pub get' command in terminal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).